# auto filling varchar column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

| StudentID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| stu001 | Ann |
| stu002 | James |

I want to create a table with auto filling StudentID column (it's a varchar column).

I found various methods to use identity in SQL Server. but I couldn't find anything similar in MySQL. can I do it with using Auto increment? I think we can use auto increment only with INT.

Comment: You can do it with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: But why do this? Why not just use a normal `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? If you also want a string, you can use a generated column that combines `stu` with the numeric ID.

Comment: @Barmar, Have you tried this with a trigger or a generated column?